# MeshLab - Curvature on mesh in specific direction

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, meshlab

I know that the curvature of a surface mesh is calculated using maximum (k1) and minimum (k2) values or so-called principal direction curvatures and then mean or Gaussian curvature are obtained.

I'm interested in curvature in a specific direction disregarding all other directions. I can obtain that if I sample the surface mesh, i.e., create cross-sections in that specific direction and then calculate the curvature of a curved line.

Is there a way to obtain curvature of a surface mesh in a specific direction?

Thank you for your help,

Marko

Comment: You have two options: computing a cross-section curve by some interpolation process of the mesh, then fitting an osculating parabola, or computing an osculating paraboloid and finding the curvature of the cross-section.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the curvature of a surface mesh is calculated using maximum (k1) and minimum (k2) values or so-called principal direction curvatures and then mean or Gaussian curvature are obtained.

That is not exactly true, that the theoretical way to compute curvatures.

In the practice, mean (H) and Gaussian (G) curvatures on each vertex are computed first (using the Laplace-Beltrami of vertex positions, and adding angles around a vertex).

Then, the module of k1 and k2 are computed as 'k1 = H + sqrt(H^2-G)' and 'k2 = H - sqrt(H^2-G)'

Then the orientation of k1 and k2 by solving a least squares system of equations based on the Euler's formula over the curvature in the direction of the edges (which is known)

So you can use same approach: compute the curvature on the direction of each edge, and estimate the curvature in your desired direction by least squares.